# How to Display the Report Alias of an Interactive Report

Tags: oracle-apex

Is there a way to display the Report Alias on a page, without having to go into the Saved Reports as the developer?

For example, I want to display on a page the direct URL to whichever interactive report the user is currently looking at (so they can bookmark directly to the report).

Normally, when asked for the direct link, I go into developer and [grab the snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXIqY.png) and send them the direct link

What I would prefer to have is the user to be able to self serve - show the direct link on the report page itself, so they can copy it for later.

Any ideas how do this in ApEx 4.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a hidden item.. lets name it P1_REPORT

*you may wish to create this on a global page*

create a display only item for your link.. lets name it P1_LINK

Now we need to create a dynamic action to pass the appropriate alias to P1_REPORT. Once we have P1_REPORT populated we can pass it to the link.

Dynamic Action

event: After Refresh

type: region

region: [your interactive report]

*true actions*

true action #1: execute JavaScript code

Fire on page load = yes

code:

```
varSelected = $("apex_ir_SAVED_REPORTS option:selected" ).text();
$s('P1_REPORT', varSelected);
```

*apex 5 will require you to leverage a static id since you can have more than 1 IR per page, but this selector will work fine on 4.2*

True action #2: Set Value

fire on load = yes

set type: pl/sql function body

code:

```
Declare
v_path varchar2(255):=null;
v_report varchar2(30):= :P1_REPORT;
Begin 
   If v_report = '1. Primary Report' then
      v_path := 'ALIAS_1';
   Elsif v_report = 'some other report' then
      v_path := 'ALIAS_2';
   End if;

  Return '<a href="f?p=311:28:&APP_SESSION.:IR_REPORT_' || v_path || '">report link</a>';
End;
```

- page items to submit: P1_REPORT
- affected element: item; P1_LINK

*sent from my iPhone*

Comment: Tried the above solution and I get the following error AJAX call returned server error ORA-06550: line 10, column 3: PLS-00372: In a procedure, RETURN statement cannot contain an expression

Comment: And what is the item P1_REPORT that you mention in the javascript

Comment: @PaulFerris sorry, I've updated my answer. I intended on renaming P1_X to P1_REPORT prior to submitting my answer, but I failed to do so.

Comment: Thanks.... in the second true action, what do you mean by affected element: item; P1_LINK

Comment: @PaulFerris the last step of the dynamic action should be a section called "affected elements". For selection type choose "item" and in the "items" field specify P1_LINK

Comment: @PaulFerris this tells the dynamic action to set the value of P1_LINK to the value that's returned by the plsql function body.

Comment: sorry for all the questions.... seems in 4.2 affected element is called "Page Items to Return". However I am still getting an error when selecting a save report. The error is AJAX call returned server error ORA-06550: line 11, column : PLS-00372: In procedure, RETURN statement cannot contain an expression... PL/SQL: Statement ignored for Execute PL?SQL Code.

Comment: @PaulFerris no, that's not true. Please take a look at the second true action.. the action should be "set value". The last step of a set value action is to specify what we're setting.. in our case you must specify that you are setting the value of an item.. then you must specify the item (P1_LINK). Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: God I am an idiot... totally misunderstood.... (sigh).... thanks got it working after fixing my stoopid mistake

Comment: @PaulFerris don't be so hard on yourself :) glad you got it working. Marking this answer as accepted would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The link isnt displaying correctly.... 

This is what is being displayed

Link to Report : <a href="http://lxweb0014.in.telstra.com.au:7780/pls/nws/f?p=311:17::IR_REPORT_">Direct Link for report</a>

And my code is 

Declare
..
Begin 
   If v_report = '1. Primary Report' then
      v_path := 'ALIAS_1';
   Elsif v_report = 'some other report' then
      v_path := 'ALIAS_2';
   End if;

  Return '<a href="http://lxweb0014.in.telstra.com.au:7780/pls/nws/f?p=311:17::IR_REPORT_' || v_path || '">Direct Link for Report</a>';
End;

Comment: @PaulFerris please provide more details. How is it displaying currently?

Comment: So it is actually not appending the v_path (or if it is, it is staying as NULL)

Comment: @PaulFerris what is the value of P1_REPORT? Did you remember to ensure that both true actions of the DA are set to fire onload too? Also ensure that the if statement in the plsql is properly referencing the names of your reports.

Comment: P1_REPORT isnt getting any value

Images of the dynamic action, and the true conditions

http://imgur.com/n8xTDFf

http://imgur.com/oTC2ZOk

http://imgur.com/WmuaCdA

Comment: @PaulFerris I see a references to p1_report, but the rest of your items refer to page 17. Also, in the plsql if statement... you see where I have if v_report = '1. Primary Report' and elsif 'some other report'? These need to match your actual your actual report names.. i.e '-- Date Change Requests --'. Also, do you see where I have 'ALIAS_1' & 'ALIAS_2'? These should be changed to match your actual report aliases.. in your original post I see an alias of 49890207

Comment: P1_REPORT is on the global page, so that should be fine, yeah?

Even with changing the PLSQL to the following, I am still not getting anything into the P1_REPORT variable

Declare
v_path varchar2(255):=null;
v_report varchar2(30):= :P1_REPORT;
Begin 
   If v_report = '1. Primary Report' then
      v_path := '9268370';
   Elsif v_report like '%Billing & Credit' then
      v_path := '58363929';
   Elsif v_report like '%Broadband' then
      v_path := '58363982';
   Elsif v_report like '%Bundle' then
      v_path := '58364009';
   Elsif v_report like '%Business Mobility' then
..

Comment: I added 

   Else v_path := '9268370';
   End if;

To the end of the PLSQL and that is the value that is always being passed. So it doesnt seem to be getting a value for v_report

Comment: @PaulFerris thanks for the additional info.. I'll look at this in greater detail within the next few hours. Now I'm wondering if the dynamic action is being fired when you change reports or if it's ONLY being fired on load. Can you have a look at the debug? Also, can you double check that p1_report is truly a global item? You may want to try putting that item on page 17 as a test

Comment: OK.. I have placed a P17_REPORT item on the page and it still isnt getting a value

If I open the chrome console and enter 

$("#apexir_SAVED_REPORTS option:selected").text()

Then I do get a value for the selected report.

If I check the session info, on page load there is a value being entered into the item, but when I select a different saved report it doesnt appear to be getting the new value 

Navigating directly to a save report sets the value of P17_REPORT on page load, but again if I change to a new report the value of P17_REPORT isnt being calculated again

Comment: OK finally got it to work

There was a bug in the javascript for the P17_REPORT item. It needed to be 

$("#apexir_SAVED_REPORTS option:selected")

and not

 $("#apex_ir_SAVED_REPORTS option:selected")

Comment: Thanks for all the help

Comment: @PaulFerris awesome, sorry about the typo. Would you mind marking the answer as accepted? I'll update my answer to reflect the script change.